# NUMPY: How to populate a 2D array with nested 'for' loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, nested-loops

So I want to know how to fill a 2d Numpy array using a nested for loops. Here is a snippet of my code below:

```
import numpy as np

y=np.ones(6000).reshape(100,60)
x=1e-5*np.ones(6000).reshape(100,60)
L=60
r=3.9
eps=0.2

def logistic(n,i):
    y[n,i]=r*x[n,i]*(1-x[n,i])
    return y[n,i]

for n in range(99):
    for i in range(L):
         x[n+1,i] = (1-eps)*logistic(n,i)
         print(x)
```

This code generates an output, but I'm not sure if this is the output I should get.
Here is a snapshot of the output here:
[image]

I'm looking for something which generates an output having the following algorithm:

1. In `x[n+1,i]` array, for `n=1`(i.e, 1st row), fill all the column elements of the `x` array with `(1-eps)*logistic(r,x)`, using `i=1,2,3...60` in a loop.
2. Then, again for `n=2`, fill all the column elements of the `x` array with `(1-eps)*logistic(r,x)`, using `i=1,2,3...60` in a loop.
3. Do this till `n=99`, and print the final array.

It'll be a great help if you figure out a way to do this. After generating the output, I also want to plot the 2d array which is basically a way to generate a coupled map lattice.

Comment: Please don't use `for` loops. You can make use of `np.arange` to obtain an array, and then try to use *broadcasting* to calculate a matrix in "bulk".

Comment: So your rows are all the same? Please clarify what output you want. Looks like you are trying to have each row be a function of the previous row, but it's not clear.

Comment: Your code would be clearer if you passed `n` and `i` to `logistic` rather than `r`.  Also are you going to make use of `y` later?  If not, why is `logistic` modifying an array rather than simply returning a value?  If all the use of indices was visible in one expression, it would be easier to detect a pattern.  For example I suspect you don't need to iterate on `i`.  Since `n+1` depends on `n` it will be harder to remove that loop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Geez! I'm a beginner to python. I don't know how your method would work for my desired output. So if you could please elucidate....

Comment: @Stuart        The rows and columns of x array are initially same, they are filled with value 1e-5 everywhere. What I want to do is: for the first row, calculate the value of the expression (1-eps)*logistic(n,i) and put that value to all the column elements of row 1. Then do the same thing for row 2, then row 3, so on..... Finally, print x array. And yes, you may say that a row is a function of the previous row, since it's a coupled data.

Comment: @hpaulj        Yeah that was a mistake, the output remains same anyway so no need  to worry. Although I have now edited my post.  Also, I don't think I'm iterating on `i`, only `n` is being iterated to `n+1` value, right?

Comment: Try to remove the `for i in range(L)` loop.  You can probably set the whole `x[n+1, :]` row with one expression based on `x[n, :]`.  Practice on a simpler case if needed.

Comment: You can also try creating an intermediate `y_log = r * x * (1 - x)`, since multiplications and sums between arrays and scalars are broadcastable

Comment: So then the values within each row will all be the same? As they are all 1e-5 on the first row and the same logistic function is applied throughout?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` doesn't seem to include a method for building an array by cumulatively applying a function to a starting value. You could possibly achieve this with [`pandas.Series.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html) or [`pandas.Series.ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html).

Without going into `pandas`, you could instead build the column as a standard list and then multiply it into a 2d array:

```
x = 1e-5
column = [x]
for _ in range(99):
    x = (1 - eps) * r * x * (1-x)
    column.append(x)
result = np.array([column] * 60).transpose()
```

Similarly you could make a generator function and create the column array using `fromiter`:

```
def cumulator(start, function, length):
    x = start
    yield x
    for _ in range(length-1):
        x = function(x)
        yield x

column = np.fromiter(cumulator(1e-5, lambda x: (1-eps) * r * x * (1-x), 100), 
                 dtype=float)
result = np.array([column] * 60).transpose()
```

Or you could build one row at a time and `vstack` (vertically stack) them:

```
row = np.full(60, 1e-5)
result = row
for _ in range(99):
    row = (1 - eps) * r * row * (1 - row)
    result = np.vstack((result, row))
```